# My custom django-admin command won't call celery task

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, django-commands

I am trying to write a custom django-admin command that executes a celery task, however the task doesn't execute and django just hangs when I try.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from myapp.tasks import my_celery_task

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print "starting task"
        my_celery_task.delay()
        print "task has been sent"
```

The output I receive when calling the command is:

```
starting task
```

I never reach the "task has been sent" line. It just hangs. I'm not sure why the task isn't running. Celery tasks are called perfectly when called by a view.

Comment: did you import `my_celery_task` task ?

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib yes, it was imported (just edited the question to show it)

Comment: Did you start a celery worker with logs to get additional information? http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#starting-the-worker

Comment: There should be something on the console, if there is an error.

Comment: @DavidD. thanks for pointing me in that direction, turns out there was a problem with RabbitMQ after upgrading to High Sierra on Mac

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was actually with RabbitMQ on Mac after upgrading to High Sierra.

Comment: What is the issue with RabbitMQ on Mac???????

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me with celery 5.1.2, but not if it is a `shared_task`

====== tasks.py

```
from celery import current_app
from celery.schedules import crontab
app = current_app._get_current_object()

@app.task
def my_celery_task():
    # Do something interesting
    return 0 # Return the result of this operation
```

====== my_command.py

```
from accounts.tasks import my_celery_task
...
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write("Queing request")
        result = my_celery_task.delay()
        self.stdout.write("Waiting for task to end")
        updated = result.wait(timeout=120.0)

        self.stdout.write(f"Returned {updated}")
```

And, if I put the task in the `celery.py` file I ended up with a deadlock which was a PITA to debug